# What data type 'A' have in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example if we are doing concatenation like:

```
'A' + columnA
```

'A' is a valid symbol for VARCHAR and CHAR as well.

So in this case we know that ***columnA*** for example is VARCHAR(8), but how SQL Server operate with 'A'?

Comment: You could always use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to find out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  I would think this would require just checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on string constants.  Alas, no.

However it is easy to check and the answer is `varchar(1)`.  Here is one way:

```
select 'A' as x, N'A' as y, 'abc ' as z
into t;

select *
from information_schema.columns;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0b1736cd6fe52c20062a3685ac7ebd7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: And `'A' + varchar_8_value` will be `varchar(9)`